# Error Your project file (.\ionic.config.json) does not contain ‘app_id’

Tags: ionic2

I am getting error while upload `ionic serve`.My ionic version is

```
global packages:

@ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.4.2
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.9.2
OS         : Windows 8
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
npm        : 3.10.9
```

Comment: have you modified the `ionic.config.json` file? It should include the following keys: `{
  "name": "YourAmazingApp",
  "app_id": "",
  "v2": true,
  "typescript": true
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am facing the same problem, after do the following step I upload my app.

**Step1** : Remove all content of `ionic.config.json` file.

**Step2** : Paste the following code.

```
{ 
    "name": "Your App Name",
    "app_id": "", 
    "v2": true, 
    "typescript": true
 }
```

**Step3**: Run `ionic link` command.

**Step4**: Run `ionic upload` command.

Answer (score 1):

Create your app in https://apps.ionic.io/ first then use ionic link , This will create new id in  your ionic config file. After that you can easily upload your app to ionic view by simply ionic upload.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct - the project needs to be in the ionic.io first